# Typescript - Handle either value or function that returns value

Tags: typescript

```
interface LoremClassNames {
    root: string;
}

interface IpsumClassNames {
    root: string;
    inner: string;
}

interface ClassNames {
    lorem?: LoremClassNames | (() => LoremClassNames);
    ipsum?: IpsumClassNames | (() => IpsumClassNames);
}

const allClassNames: ClassNames = {};

function getClassNames<K extends keyof ClassNames>(
    componentName: K
): ClassNames[K] extends (a: unknown) => unknown
    ? ReturnType<ClassNames[K]>
    : ClassNames[K] | undefined {
    const classNames = allClassNames[componentName];

    if (typeof classNames === 'function') {
        return classNames();
    }

    return classNames;
}

export const lorem: LoremClassNames | undefined = getClassNames('lorem');
export const ipsum: IpsumClassNames | undefined = getClassNames('ipsum');
```

In the above code, I have an interface `ClassNames` that can contain a series of either objects, or functions that return those objects. I'm trying to write a function `getClassNames` that returns the object defined by the key. However, I just can't seem to work out where I'm going wrong.

I'm getting the following type error on the `return classNames()` line:

```
Type 'LoremClassNames' is not assignable to type 'ClassNames[K] extends (a: unknown) => unknown ? ReturnType<ClassNames[K]> : ClassNames[K] | undefined'.
```

And the following error on the `return classNames` line:

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ClassNames[K] extends (a: unknown) => unknown ? ReturnType<ClassNames[K]> : ClassNames[K] | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is 3 fold.

Because `ClassNames[K]` is not a naked generic type parameter, it isn't being distributed in the conditional. Basically, you're doing:

```
(LoremClassNames | (() => LoremClassNames) | undefined) extends (a: unknown) => unknown
```

Which will never evaluate to the true branch. I'm pretty sure you wanted to be distributed, and in that case, you could create another type parameter and have it default to `ClassNames[K]`:

```
function getClassNames<K extends keyof ClassNames, T = ClassNames[K]>(
    componentName: K
): T extends () => unknown
    ? ReturnType<T>
    : T {
```

Another big change: using `() => unknown`. It simply doesn't make sense to use `(a: unknown) => unknown` because the function types don't have any parameters. So if you remove the parameter, the function types will now "extend" (be assignable to) `() => unknown`.

This is now what the conditional looks like when it is distributed:

```
(LoremClassNames extends () => unknown ? ... : LoremClassNames) |
((() => LoremClassNames) extends () => unknown ? ReturnType<...> : ...) |
(undefined extends () => unknown ? ... : undefined)
```

Which is just `LoremClassNames | undefined`.

Finally, there is the problem of the return statements erroring, not matching the annotated return type. Since TypeScript just can't relate control flow and type parameters, it just "gets confused" and errors out.

What I like to do is move the troublesome annotations into an *overload*. It's effectively shoo-ing it aside and plus, you can choose what parameter types you want inside the function body.

```
// moved into overload; consumers can use this and only this signature
function getClassNames<K extends keyof ClassNames, T = ClassNames[K]>(
    componentName: K
): T extends () => unknown
    ? ReturnType<T>
    : T;
// implementation gets to use these types instead
function getClassNames(componentName: keyof ClassNames) {
    const classNames = allClassNames[componentName];

    if (typeof classNames === 'function') {
        return classNames();
    }

    return classNames;
}
```

The downside is that TypeScript doesn't check if the implementation body actually matches the overloads, only if the overload signatures are compatible with the implementation. I don't really see any problem with this though, as you would need to use an assertion otherwise (i.e, TJ's answer).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHsoQLYGEA2cAzkQHJzYRHIDeAsAFDLPJTrpgBcyRYUoAcwDcjAL6NGoSLEQoAkgAciAVzyES5StXpMWbDt178Qwxi2SgQ0Q30EiG4hpPDR4SZAWJkKVWmZb4mDgA-NwYWGpemr4APsgAFPEAlMgAvAB8aEGRGj5ESfbmwEqqociKKjneWshxiSkZ5SVV0fn2jowI6CC8yHD4+J65WtxD1b6ptKL2jDDKIAhgwN3IAhBgY60APADSyBAAHpAgACbUANYQAJ7oMB7q40QANMgAKmn3UXkA2jsAuul4v5mF1sApuhBwNFuDtGEluO9DsczgkGpl5ucQOgAO4gYHIYLIABK62UUBAryuCggW1e6XxCPscwWSxWaw2D1a8VB4KsUJ83EuNzumzyKR05i6PTAyAQnLyH36g3lWm+PIh-MofxmumYwDu8TAVIgt1lKomqUmAHJmYtliAreL8eYsGAySAzV8tMlCiwOrrWKTyZ7hlR2hIGIdwVAZVLeoEImFsqKanF5icIDBQBATh92SmqPErQmcI77FHMLHur1ipVuBVVAXqGnTpns7nJvnzUQi7XVGWgA)

Comment: Distribution. Of course! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I don't know why TypeScript's doing what it's doing there, in particular I don't understand why when you've done the `=== "function"` test, it thinks the return type of `classNames()` is `LoremClassName`, specifically, rather than `LoremClassName | IpsumClassName`.

I can get it to work, but only with a type assertion, which is unsatisfying:

```
function getClassNames<K extends keyof ClassNames>(componentName: K) {
    const classNames = allClassNames[componentName];

    const result = (
        typeof classNames === "function" ? classNames() : classNames
    ) as Exclude<ClassNames[K], (...args: any[]) => any>;
    return result;
}

export const lorem = getClassNames("lorem");
//           ^? const lorem: LoremClassNames | undefined
export const ipsum = getClassNames("ipsum");
//           ^? const ipsum: IpsumClassNames | undefined
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHsoQLYGEA2cAzkQHJzYRHIDeAsAFDLPJTrpgBcyRYUoAcwDcjAL6NGoSLEQoAkgAciAVzyES5StXpMWbDt178Qwxi2SgQ0Q30EiG4hpPDR4SZAWJkKVWmZb4mDgA-NwYWGpemr4APsgAFPEAlMgAvAB8aEGRGj5ESfbmwEqqociKKjneWshxiSkZ5SVV0fn2jowAJhAIhFjICOggvMhw+PieuVrck9VU9owwyiAIYMBDyAIQYLOtADwA0sgQAB6QIJ3UANYQAJ7oMB7qc0Tp8YPYCkMQ4NHcBykdOZBsMwANnq00qNxrs8gBtD5fKy-HwAXQWumYIJGWBU+DBqQS-nMzDAtwUEAe4KieTSqUJACIlis1kMGchgtSplRkshuL0aVpicgUsRkABRE69ZTdPawrRwg6ogA0CQAdBq4FABERuHAQLc4aiGpl9bd0oU9NtlFAQKwqMp8e0JAxTl8oGDsWDAhEoVsdhC8vEGT6cAyCowAPSRkmxgB6wUYbswnqGI2KlT923lPIZGdU4fs0djJITjCAA)